# How to get source file by php script from .htaccess Action/AddHandler

Tags: php, .htaccess, watermark

I making a simple script to add a watermark image to all image files in directory.

So, I have .htaccess:

```
AddHandler watermarked .jpg 
AddHandler watermarked .jpeg 
AddHandler watermarked .gif 
AddHandler watermarked .png 

Action watermarked /spimg/vitowatermark.php
```

So, now on each image request from this directory, vitowatermark.php is working.

How can I get source image file, user requested from my PHP script, to put watermark on it and generate answer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool, I find answer to this question myself.

```
$filename =  $_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"];
```

Comment: Is there a simple way of outputting the file to the browser with its original headers?